# Set LineRenderer position

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, renderer

I'm trying to set the LineRenderer position in the center of the parent
but it's set in the wrong position

it's should be in this position

[image: center]

Here is the code that I tried

```
Vector3 SumPointsVectors = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
// filledRenderer point int Line rendere
 foreach (var child in filledRenderer)
 {
     SumPointsVectors += child;
 }

 Vector3 Center = SumPointsVectors / filledRenderer.Length;
 _lineRenderer.transform.position = Center;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virgilcwyile answer: The line renderer game object when you select is showing you the centre point right? So you can create a GameObject and place it in that centre point, then Make the LineRenderer a child of that GameObject. Then set this GameObject child of your Cylinder Parent. After doing that, you can reset the GameObject's position to Vector3.Zero.

Alternate Solution: Another solution would be to create a Custom Mesh from your Points and then set the pivot.

here the answer in unity answer
http://answers.unity.com/answers/1770136/view.html

Answer (score 1):

When you make the Component the Line will start to render from the Origin (0,0,0)
However, you can change that by setting the positions. [Link to Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPosition.html)

Set the start point to your desired position in Vector Coordinates.